# Jquery trying to change on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to programming a site and hide nav bar if the user scroll but I do not know what's wrong with my code toggle works fine but not if I scroll

Is there something bad with my code ?

```
<script>

   x = 0;   
  $(function() {
      $(".icon-menu").click(function(){
         $("nav").toggle();
      });


     $(".container").scroll(function(){
        $(".menu_txt").text( x+= 1);
        if (x > 30) {
           $("nav").hide();
         }
      });

  });

</script>
```

I really appreciate a hand
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to get the scrollbar status in jQuery is as follows:

```
$(".container").scrollTop();
```

This will return the number of pixels from the top that the element has scrolled down. You can check this value inside your .scroll() function and hide the nav when the value of .scrollTop() is greater than your desired pixel height.